# Complex Linq to Entities Query

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have done simple LINQ queries but I am stumped on the 2 I need to create now.  Basically I am going to get a class ID sent in.  I will post the classes the entities are based on below.

```
public class ScheduledClass
{
    public ScheduledClass()
    {
        Attendees = new List<ClassAttendee>();
    }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a topic")]
    public int ClassTopicID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Topic")]
    public virtual ClassTopic ClassTopic { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int ClassTypeID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Class Type")]
    public virtual ClassType ClassType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Class Date")] 
    public DateTime ClassDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Attendees")] 
    public virtual ICollection<ClassAttendee> Attendees { get; set; }
}

 public ClassTopic()
    {
        Products = new List<ClassTopicProduct>();
    }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Products")]
    public virtual ICollection<ClassTopicProduct> Products { get; set; }
}

public class ClassTopicProduct
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int ClassTopicID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ClassTopicID")]
    public ClassTopic ClassTopic { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProductID")]
    public ProductType ProductType { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerEmail
{

    public CustomerEmail()
    {
        CustomerEmailModules = new List<CustomerEmailModule>();
    }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Product Update")]
    public Boolean SendProductUpdateEmail { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Expiration ")]
    public Boolean SendExpirationEmail { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Products")]
    public virtual ICollection<CustomerEmailModule> CustomerEmailModules { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerEmailModule
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int CustomerEmailID { get; set; }

    public CustomerEmail CustomerEmail { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int? ProductID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProductID")]
    public ProductType ProductType { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**

```
public class ProductType
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a product type description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProductTypeDetail> ProductDetails { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**

So I am basically trying to send emails to people who might be interested in an upcoming class.  Each class has a class topic.  The class topic has 1 or more products associated with them.  When I get the Class ID I need to go get all of the products associated with the class topic for the class.  Once I have that I need to go look at CustomerEmails.  Each CustomerEmail has any number of products that they are interested in associated with them.  I need to find any CustomerEmail that has CustomerEmailModules where the PRoductID = Any of the product IDs in the Class Topic Products results.  Here is what I tried to do below that is not working.

```
 public JsonResult GetEmailClassInterest(int id)
    {
         var classprods = UoW.ScheduledClasses 
            .Where(o => o.ID == id)
            .Select(p => new
            {
                p.ClassTopic.Products
            });

        var customeremails = from p in UoW.CustomerEmails where classprods.Any(z => z.Products.Any(x => x.ID == p.ID)) select p.Email;
        return Json(customeremails, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The query seems to run through ok but I get no results and there shoudl be base don the data I have.  If anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong I would appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: I figured out part of the issue.  In the last line I am comparing IDs of the 2 objects.  I changed this portion z.Products.Any(x => x.ID == p.ID)) to be z.Products.Any(x => x.ProductID == p.ID)) but there is still an issue because I do not want to comparte it to the ID of the CustomerEmail I need to compare it to all of the IDS of the CustomerEmailModules tied to the CustomerEmail.

Comment: Does CustomerEmailModules have a FK to CustomerEmail? Because you don't have that as an annotation.

Comment: It does have it as a ForeignKey usually that happens for me by defualt by sayign CustomerEmail contains a Virtual ICollection of CustomerEmailModules and having a field scalled <table Name> in this case CustomerEmail folled by Id

Comment: What does the ProductType object look like?

Comment: I added in the ProductType class up above

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
var classprods = UoW.ScheduledClasses 
            .Where(o => o.ID == id)
            .SelectMany(sched => sched.ClassTopic.Products.Select(prod => prod.ProductID));

var customerEmails = UoW.CustomerEmailModules.Include("CustomerEmails")
                                             .Where(mod => mod.ProductID != null && classprods.Contains(mod.ProductID)
                                             .Select(mod => mod.CustomerEmail.Email);
```

Comment: I get the following error Error 21 'System.Linq.IQueryable<int>' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Contains<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, TSource)' has some invalid arguments